# Bluetooth audio missing on Windows 8

Tags: bluetooth, windows-8

Before upgrading my laptop to Windows 8 (Professional, from MSDN, which purported to be RTM), I was able to use my computer headset as hands-free audio for my cell phone (HTC HD2, but nothing changed on it).  After the upgrade, I can select Dial-Up Networking, PAN, Serial Port, and Telephony profiles, but none of the Audio profiles are available in either direction.

This is an integrated BCM2046 radio, and the driver version is Broadcom 12.0.0.10.

[image]

The [Broadcom Bluetooth Update](http://www.broadcom.com/support/bluetooth/update.php) recognizes a compatible radio and downloads software, but the install is blocked because Windows 8 says it isn't compatible.

In addition, Windows 8 is supposed to ship with all the required bluetooth profiles for Hands-Free and Bluetooth Audio.

How can I get the audio services working again with my Bluetooth phone?

Comment: Update: Broadcom now has a Bluetooth Update that's compatible with Windows 8.  And I now have an Android Jellybean phone.  But Windows 8 still isn't letting me use the computer as a headset for the phone.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to bet that you should be using the 4.0 driver found here

http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/downloads/detail.page?DocID=DS031999&rss=true

Reference:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w8itprohardware/thread/5526e50f-11e6-4f06-bfd4-a06e29419521